# Building a rudimentary Inventory

Tags: c

I am very new to C. I have tried to build an Inventory using several techniques i thought would do the job. There is a Problem:

Everytime i loop this code my Inventory goes back to {"Banana", "Axe", "Pepsi"}.

How can i avoid this. I have to declare it and i want to populate it with these 3 items but i also want it to be updated.

thx !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char inventory[10][10] = {"Banana", "Axe", "Pepsi"};
    unsigned int itemCount = sizeof(inventory) / sizeof(inventory[0]);
    // calculate the free space
    unsigned int freeSpace = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        if (inventory[i][0] == '\0') // Check if the first character of the string is the null terminator
        {
            freeSpace++;
        }
    }
    printf("freeSpace = %d\n", freeSpace);
    //nextAvailableItemSlot
    unsigned int freeItemSlot = itemCount - freeSpace;

    int options;

    printf("What would you like to do? \n1 = Display inventory \n2 = Add an item to the inventory\n");
    scanf("%d", &options);

    if (options == 1)
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(inventory) / sizeof(inventory[0]); i++)
        {
            printf("[%d]%s\n", i, inventory[i]);
        }
    }

    if (options == 2)
    {
        printf("%d", itemCount);
        char newItem[10];
        printf("Which item would you like to add to your inventory?");
        scanf("%s", newItem);
        // Copy the newItem to the next free Inventory Slot
        strcpy(inventory[freeItemSlot], newItem);
        printf("You have added %s to your inventory.\n", newItem);
        // Print inventory
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(inventory) / sizeof(inventory[0]); i++)
        {
            printf("[%d]%s\n", i, inventory[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i already tried to put the whole inventory into a seperate function but i cant seem to get around the problem that sooner or later i meet "char inventory[10][10] = {"Banana", "Axe", "Pepsi"};" again.

Comment: What do you mean with *Everytime i loop this code*? When you run it a new time? Why did not you try do add a loop *inside* the code?

Comment: Seems to work here: https://godbolt.org/z/d8eaW681s Can you explain more what you mean by "Everytime i loop this code"? What is the input you are providing? What output are you expecting?

Comment: If you want to keep informations between separate invocations, you have to *persist* in in a permanent storage like a disk file or a database. For your example, you could use a text file, with one item per line.

Comment: @Peter Kirsch, I'd expect `freeItemSlot++` someplace after adding an item.

Comment: I realise this is just an exercise, but you should be aware that scanf("%s", newItem); is unsafe, and vulnerable to buffer overflow, so you would need to do this a different way for serious code. Also, if you don't need to store the inventory as Retired Ninja suggested, you need a loop in the code. Something like while(freeSpace >0), and add an exit option.

Answer (score 1):

> Everytime i loop this code my Inventory goes back to {"Banana", "Axe", "Pepsi"}.

*If you want to keep informations between separate invocations, you have to persist in in a permanent storage like a disk file or a database. For your example, you could use a text file, with one item per line.* – Serge Ballesta

Other than that, if you want to continue asking for input, your code should be wrapped inside a `while`/`do-while` loop, with perhaps a third option that would exit the code.

Side-note: There is a buffer-overflow vulnerability in your code:

```
char newItem[10];
printf("Which item would you like to add to your inventory?");
scanf("%s", newItem)
```

What happens when the length of the input is greater than `sizeof newItem`?
Consider changing it to:

```
if (scanf("%9s", newItem) != 1) {
    complain();
}
```

Or use `fgets()`.

You can also forego copying the input to the `inventory` array by reading directly into it.

You also do not need the first loop to calculate the number of free items, you can simply use the constant `7`.

*I'd expect `freeItemSlot++` someplace after adding an item.* – chux - Reinstate Monica

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment freeSpace after every new item as @Reinstate Monica mentioned.

You also have to use an infinite loop to repeatedly ask for new item

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char inventory[10][10] = {"Banana", "Axe", "Pepsi"};
    unsigned int itemCount = sizeof(inventory) / sizeof(inventory[0]);
    // calculate the free space
    unsigned int freeSpace = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    { 
        if (inventory[i][0] == '\0') // Check if the first character of the string is the null terminator
        { 
            freeSpace++;
        } 
    } 
    printf("freeSpace = %d\n", freeSpace);
    //nextAvailableItemSlot
    unsigned int freeItemSlot = itemCount - freeSpace;

    int options;
    while (1) { 
        printf("What would you like to do? \n1 = Display inventory \n2 = Add an item to the inventory\n");
        scanf("%d", &options);

        if (options == 1)
        { 
                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(inventory) / sizeof(inventory[0]); i++)
                { 
                printf("[%d]%s\n", i, inventory[i]);
                } 
        } 

        if (options == 2)
        { 
                if (freeItemSlot == 10) { 
                        puts("Inventory Array is full");
                        continue;
                } 
                printf("%d", itemCount);
                char newItem[10];
                printf("Which item would you like to add to your inventory? ");
                scanf("%s", newItem);                           
                // Copy the newItem to the next free Inventory Slot
                strcpy(inventory[freeItemSlot], newItem);       
                freeItemSlot++;                                 
                printf("You have added %s to your inventory.\n", newItem);
                // Print inventory                              
                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(inventory) / sizeof(inventory[0]); i++)
                {                                               
                        printf("[%d]%s\n", i, inventory[i]);
                } 
        }
 }
}
```